# How to make a Javafx app use the screen resolution that's passed into it in Scene Builder?

Tags: java, macos, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have the following JavaFx application and use Scene builder.
I want my scene to have the screen resolution **1920*1080**:
[image: Parameters for set screen resolution]

My display has following resolution:

[image: Image showing screen resolution as 2880 by 1800 pixels]

But after running code I have the application that can't even fit into my window. Is this caused by incorrect scaling, or something else?

[image: Desktop showing application not fitting in window]

Comment: "Is this caused by incorrect scaling, or something else?" -> most likely, something else.  It is impossible to know what without a [mcve].

Comment: You can set the max/min size for a stage if you want.  But, from your screenshot, you also have other issues with your layout, so fixing the stage size alone, won't fix your issue.  Also, scene size is different from stage size and you specially talk only about scene size.  So, you could set the scene's initial size in its constructor, then set the max/min size of the stage to the current stage size after the stage is shown, this will ensure a scene of your required size, but fixing the layout inside your scene is another matter.

Comment: I don't think from your description that you want your "scene to have the screen resolution". You appear to want a scene of a fixed pixel size, regardless of the [graphics display resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution).  Perhaps you should edit the question to add more clarity about what you want and remove anything which is potentially misleading.

Answer (score 0):

this ?

```
double height=  Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getHeight();   
double width=   Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getWidth();  
scene = new Scene(root,width , height);
```

tho your title is asking for something that's done by default as size infos are registered in the xml used to create your views.

Comment: Nope, see the asker’s comment on the other answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/70112747/1155209

Answer (score -1):

Try Adding the below piece of code in your main class. This will maximize the window to fit your screen resolution

**Note:** However the size of the icons which are shown on your app screen may not change.

```
stage.setMaximized(true);
```

Comment: this is not i've asked for. I need not to fit my scene on full screen, but to have the scene with specific resolution (in my case, 1920*1080) to be correctly presented on the screen